# Inverting photo using pre-defined material colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, color-conversion, affinity-designer, affinity-publisher

I like to use black-backgrounded slides for my conference presentations. However, as research papers use white-backgrounded figures, they should be converted. A good option is inverting the colours. **However, often the inverting does not give nice colors. Is it possible to do the same process but use nice, predefined colors, e.g. material colors?**

*Is possible, Affinity-based solutions are especially appreciated!*

BEFORE

[image]

AFTER

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously want to keep red and blue hues, but invert the luminosity levels. It can be done in systems which allow a little more "what actually is adjusted"-options for the curves adjustment tool than Photoshop. Free systems with it are at least programs GIMP, Krita and Paint.NET. I do not have Affinity Photo available now, so I cannot check it.

Here's the luminosity level inversion done with Curves+ in Paint.NET.

[image]

You may want to keep the strongest color in the middle of the graph. That needs a twist in the color inversion curve. The next screenshot is from Krita where the curve is selected to affect Lightness:

[image]

Curves+ is one of the free add-ons included in pyrochild effect collection. GIMP and Krita do not need any add-ons.

You may change red and blue to other colors by applying Hue/Saturation shifts. Some programs allow changing one color at a time. For ex. Photoshop has for it hue range limited Hue/Saturation adjustment. Paint.NET needs for the same a free add-on.

All bitmap image editors allow global hue and saturation adjustments. The next example of it is in Krita:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Nice" is subjective. Not sure what's wrong with the orange/green, but...

If you want to keep the red/blue, invert the image and then apply a Hue/Saturation adjustment to alter the color back to red/blue...

[image]

I simply dragged the top slider to the left.